# Multiple tables join echo with while

Tags: php, mysql, html-table, echo

I'm now hopeless about this problem and that's why I'm here. I'm kind of a starter in PHP and mysql programming. I searched for a solution on the web but I wasn't succeeded. I'm working on a project what is a car repairing administration system. This is a part of it that I need.

I have two tables:

```
repairs (j_id /this is the primary key/, rendszam, javitas, megjegyzes, datum) 
and 
pictures (kep_id /this is the primary key/, j_id /it's from repairs j_id/, kepnev)
```

I need to display a result in a table, where I can see that which of the repairs have a picture in the pictures table, but without redundancy, so I don't want multiple repair rows that are similar to eachother, but one repair row with multiple picture columns after it.

What I have done already:

```
<?php
$sql = "SELECT $tbl_name2.j_id, $tbl_name2.rendszam, $tbl_name2.javitas, $tbl_name2.megjegyzes, $tbl_name2.datum, $tbl_name3.kepnev FROM $tbl_name2, $tbl_name3 WHERE $tbl_name2.j_id=$tbl_name3.j_id";

$result = mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error());

while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
    echo "<tr><td>" . $row[$i] . "</td>";
    echo "<td>" . $row[$i + 1] . "</td>";
    echo "<td>" . $row[$i + 2] . "</td>";
    echo "<td>" . $row[$i + 3] . "</td>";
    echo "<td>" . $row[$i + 4] . "</td>";
    echo "<td>" . $row[$i + 5] . "</td>";
}
?>
```

This one displays information like this:

```
repair id | picture

1    |    fdgdfg.jpg
1    |    fgdfg.jpg
1    |    fghh.jpg
25   |    dfg.jpg
25   |    jkjk.jpg
```

But I don't want to have multiple repair rows but one repair row with multiple pictures after it.

I tried this:

```
$sql2="SELECT DISTINCT $tbl_name2.j_id, $tbl_name3.kepnev FROM $tbl_name2, $tbl_name3 WHERE $tbl_name2.j_id=$tbl_name3.j_id";

$result2=mysql_query($sql2) or die(mysql_error());

$sql="SELECT $tbl_name2.j_id, $tbl_name2.rendszam, $tbl_name2.javitas, $tbl_name2.megjegyzes, $tbl_name2.datum, $tbl_name3.kepnev FROM $tbl_name2, $tbl_name3 WHERE $tbl_name2.j_id=$tbl_name3.j_id GROUP BY j_id;

$result=mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error());

while($row=mysql_fetch_array($result))
{
echo "<tr><td>".$row[$i]."</td>";
echo "<td>".$row[$i+1]."</td>";
echo "<td>".$row[$i+2]."</td>";
echo "<td>".$row[$i+3]."</td>";
echo "<td>".$row[$i+4]."</td>";
echo "<td>".$row[$i+5]."</td>";
while($sor=mysql_fetch_array($result2))
    {
        if($sor['j_id']==$row[$i]){
        echo "<td><a href=kepek/".$sor['kepnev']." target=_blank>".$sor['kepnev']."</a></td>";
        }
    }

}
```

The sql statement differs in the group by in $sql, but this one displays the results like this:

```
 repair id | picture

    1    |    fdgdfg.jpg | fgdfg.jpg | fghh.jpg
    25   |
```

So it's just not continuing after the first repair id, not showing the repair pictures for repair id 25.

I don't know, how can I get it right. I need a table which displays information like this:

```
repair id | picture

   1    |    fdgdfg.jpg | fgdfg.jpg | fghh.jpg
   25   |    dfg.jpg | jkjk.jpg
```

Could you help me out in this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This sounds fairly straightforward, looks like you're off to a good start.

I've done something similar in the past, and I just used a variable to keep track of the current ID being displayed and the previously displayed ID.  Here's a quick code sample to outline what I mean by that.

```
while($row=mysql_fetch_array($result))
{
    $currentID=$row[$i];
    if ($currentID != $lastID) { 
        echo "</tr><tr><td>".$row[$i]."</td>"; 
    } else {
        echo "<td>".$row[$i]."</td>";   
    }
    $lastID=$row[$i];
}
```

So, the idea is to keep track of what the last ID was.  In the next row, if the ID is the same, just output <td>"variable goes here"</td> to keep it on the same column.  If the ID changed, end the row and create a new row using </tr><tr>".  Feel free to comment if you need more help.

Comment: Thank you, with a bit of editing it solved the problem. I learned something new today too. Thanks.